# Need to save cropped image from croppic to my sql database

Tags: php, mysql, image, save, crop

I am using CROPPIC (http://www.croppic.net/) to crop my image, everything works fine. Cropped image is getting saved in folder.

I am just facing 1 issue, I am not able to save the image in database (sql database, using php).

Using the same coding for everything from http://www.croppic.net/.

Link for my php files: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0pv6f8tqdxkaj4p/AADlZGY7AvhMJtMvT-5-yM4Qa?dl=0

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0pv6f8tqdxkaj4p/AADlZGY7AvhMJtMvT-5-yM4Qa?dl=0

Comment: Show your code here, where you get problem.

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757659/how-to-store-images-in-mysql-database-using-php

Comment: actually i need to save cropped image in database, but dont get image path in sql query

Comment: i have uplaoded my code to the above link... there are 3 files connected and i want to have the insert code in "add_new_product2.php"

Comment: and actual cropping happens in other 2 files, img_crop_to_file.php & img_save_to_file.php