# I Want to Upload an image in database through php,the image is not uploading in database

Tags: php, mysql

i tried to upload an image but when getimagesize the image is empty it is returning false.. and warning is coming ,it is not saving in database 
.the database name is project and table name is images and fields are name and image .Here is a code...

```
<?php
 ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout',300);
 ini_set('default_socket_timeout',300);

?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">
<input type="file" name="image"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
</form>
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
{
  echo "Connected successfully";
}
 //data upload
 if( isset($_POST['submit'] ))
 {
     if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])==FALSE) //image size is checked
     {
            echo "upload image";
     }
     else
     {
        $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image=file_get_contents($image);
        $image= base64_encode($image);
        saveimage($name,$image);
      }
    }
    function saveimage($name,$image)
    {
      $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
      mysql_select_db("project",$conn);
      $result = mysql_query("insert into images(name,image) values('$name','$image')");    //query implemented

    }
    ?>      //function written to save image
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Error message? What is the column type of `image`? Is it `BLOB`? Have you considered storing images in your system rather than in your database? Try using `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: You should store image in system and store that image folder path in database...

Comment: @Logan Wayne ,this the error message                                                 Undefined index: image in C:\wamp\www\imageupload.php on line 37                getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp\www\imageupload.php on line 37   and column type is LONGBLOB nd i trying to store image in local server nd i tried using  === it is still not working

Comment: @Piyush i want to directly store image in database

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757659/how-to-store-images-in-mysql-database-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit this line

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: a new warning came,Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\imageupload.php on line 58 and  Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Error reading result set's header in C:\wamp\www\imageupload.php on line 58   and still the image is not stored in database

Comment: ok replace this code

 $uploads_dir = '/uploads';
     $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
        $name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
        $image=file_get_contents($image);
        $image= base64_encode($image);
        move_uploaded_file($image, "$uploads_dir/$name");

Comment: still warning,Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\imageupload.php on line 66      and  Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Error reading result set's header in C:\wamp\www\imageupload.php on line 66

Comment: create uploads folder in your project

Comment: oh,i removed saveimage function now its working,but i want to save image in database.please help

Comment: ok chenge insert query

 $result = mysql_query("insert into images(name) values('$name')");

Comment: after creating folder also image is not saving in folder.

Comment: saveimage($name,$image); line is required

Comment: still not saving in a folder

Comment: $result = mysql_query("insert into images(name) values('$name')")or die("cant insert");
and tell me what is output

Comment: the output is -cant insert

Comment: check your database name

Comment: database name is "project"

Comment: in your data base run this query

     
           CREATE TABLE images
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
image VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ( id ));
);

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '&quot;. &quot;id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, &quot;. &quot;name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, &quot;. &quot;image VA' at line 1    this error came

Comment: remove your old table who's name is images
after run this query

Comment: oh,thanx its working,but what was the reason it was not working  and now how to store the image in database

Comment: mistake in your database

Comment: the image is not uploading,the query with name is working earlier query is not working.

Comment: did you create folder the name is "uploads" in your project directory

Comment: yes,i made that.this query is working $result = mysql_query("insert into images(name) values('$name')")or die("cant insert");  and this is not  $result = mysql_query("insert into images(name,image) values('$name','$image')");

Comment: can u help me answering another question,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590041/to-retrieve-the-image-from-the-database-which-is-stored-in-binary-format

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout',300);
 ini_set('default_socket_timeout',300);

?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
</form>
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
{
  echo "Connected successfully";
}
 //data upload
 if( isset($_POST['submit'] ))
 {
    mysql_select_db("project",$conn);
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
        $name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $result = mysql_query("insert into images(name,image) values('.$name.','.$image.')");  
    mysql_close($conn); 
    }?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: warnings,Undefined index: image in C:\wamp\www\imageupload.php on line 27 and Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\wamp\www\imageupload.php on line 27 and Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\wamp\www\imageupload.php on line 28

Comment: $name=basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

Comment: it did not made any change

Comment: change enctype from "multipart/formdata" to "multipart/form-data"