# To retrieve the image from the database which is stored in binary format

Tags: php, sql

In this image is stored in database in binary format and i want to retrieve it, it is displaying as an empty box,i want the image should display as an output.There might be some error in display function .Here is the code....

```
<?php
 ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout',300);
 ini_set('default_socket_timeout',300);

?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">
</form>

<?php

// Create connection
 $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
 die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
   else
  {
     echo "Connected successfully";
   }

 //data upload
 if( isset($_POST['submit'] ))
{
  if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])===FALSE)//to get image size
 {
   echo "upload image";
 }
   else
 {

   $uploads_dir = '/newimages';
   $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); 
   $name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
   $image=file_get_contents($image); 
   $image= base64_encode($image); 
   move_uploaded_file($image, "$uploads_dir/$name");
   saveimage($name,$image);
   displayimage();   //display function is called to display images
  }
 }
 function saveimage($name,$image)
 {
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
    mysql_select_db("project",$conn);
    $result = mysql_query("insert into images(name,image) values('$name','$image')");
  }
    //display function
  function displayimage()
  {
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
    mysql_select_db("project",$conn);
    $result = mysql_query("select * from images");
    while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo'<img height="100" width="100" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[2].'">';  //to display image
     }
   mysql_close($conn);
   }
   ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: [PHP is not the best technology for Blobs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40913).

Answer (score 0):

Use `base64_encode` to get desire result

```
echo'<img height="100" width="100" src="data:image;base64,'.base64_encode($row[2]).'">';
```

If its not working then try this

Create a file called `show_blob_img.php` and put bellow content there

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
mysql_select_db("project",$conn);
// Get ID from url I guess your primary key is id if not then change with that
$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("select * from images where id="+$id);
$row =mysql_fetch_array($result);
/*** set the headers and display the image ***/
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
/*** output the image ***/
echo $row[2];
mysql_close($conn);
```

And change your

```
echo'<img height="100" width="100" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[2].'">';  
//to display image
```

**to**

```
// I guess your first field is id if not then replace it with proper field
echo'<img src="show_blob_img.php?id="'.$row[0].' height="100" width="100" />'; 
//to display image
```

**Note**:

> You have to create another page and make that page type to image/jpg
>   so it can display image.This page get your image id so you can get
>   that image from database and You need to echo that image code.

Comment: Did you visit given link @upasana

Comment: i saw that, but cant u tell if there is any error in my code,as i dont want any specific image to display ,i u can help

Comment: Ok.Let me see @upsana

Comment: Do you understand what I want to told you@upasana

Comment: If you still not got it then see this tutorial http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Storing-Images-in-MySQL-with-PHP.html

Comment: if u can help in any way,to alter my code as i m not able to figure out my problem from above specified link...and i tried what u told but unable to get correct answer...

Comment: Did you check my edited answer.I use your code to show the picture.Better debug your code to find out the problem.

Comment: ok,i made another php file ,please tell me about the changes i have to make to get id or any other in above code and how to call that file..please help

Comment: that i did and called as <img src="getimage.php"> //getimage is my file my database first filed is id and i want all images should display as they are coming.

Comment: Dear Upasana you should give table structure and some other details

Comment: my table structure is -----                                                                                     first field is id and second name and third image (LONGBLOB) and everything is working ok image is stored in binary format in database but at retrieval i m just getting empty box on html page.

Comment: So your getimage.php file content will be like      $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');
    mysql_select_db("project",$conn);
    
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query("select * from images where id="+$id);
    $row =mysql_fetch_array($result);
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    echo $row['image'];
    mysql_close($conn);

Comment: What did you put in the newly created file

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo'<img height="100" width="100" src="../uploads/'.$row['name'].'">';  //to display image
     }
```

Comment: Try this
echo'<img height="100" width="100" src="/uploads/'.$row['name'].'">';