# Android app to send photos among users

Tags: android, database, whatsapp

It really has been difficult to find an answer of how to share photos among users. What I have already done is storing strings into a MySQL database via PHP, but when it comes to an image, it is impossible for me to store it into MySQL as a blob type. I know this is not the best approach as it is said that the best option is to save the reference to that photo as a link, but... my question is how do apps like WhatsApp, Instagram, etc share picutures? Don't they store it into databases? How can a user receive back the data of that photo then?
I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Hi ninithblue! Welcome to SO.Could you show us the code?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried already, and give more info about the technology and approach you used.

Comment: I wouldnt use PHP unless its a secure connection. I would use Firebase or Parse. Firebase might be a better option for this, but thats up to you. BTW, a picture is nothing more than data, dont over think saving it into a database. If you are using PHP, https://stackoverflow.com/a/26758516/8200290 ............. if you want to use it with android..... https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server-using-php-mysql/